# cant load static file in django

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm

I copied a HTML page with many images and javascript codes.

I created the `static folder` and did everything that is needed, and when I'm tying to load the source with `static tag` such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

I'm still getting an error:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

All it did is to add `static` in the url and I dont understand why?

I cant find how to load jinja in pycharm so my tags are white.

Comment: yes, I did exactly what is written

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)?

> Serving the files
>
> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.
>
> See Deploying static files for proper strategies to serve static files in production environments.

Comment: i ran the command python manage.py collectstatic, and it was not the issue